# writing List <string> elements to excel

Tags: c#

I'm just using a simple code to write a list of string to excel as  following

```
        Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        string myPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + path + "\\reselts.xlsx";
        excelApp.Workbooks.Open(myPath);

        List <string> allterms = new List<string>(alltext.Split(' '));

         allterms= allterms.Distinct().ToList();
        allterms.RemoveAll(String.IsNullOrEmpty);

        for (int i = 1; i < allterms.Count + 1; i++ )
        {

            excelApp.Cells[i, 1] = allterms[i];

        }
        excelApp.Visible = true;
```

But I got an error "index was out of range" ! what is wrong with my procedure ? can any help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`allterms.Count` is the total number of items in the `List`. Your loop is trying to access `Count + 1`, which doesn't exist.

For example, say there are 10 items in `allterms`. The total **count** is equal to `10` and the index ranges from `0 - 9`, which is 10 items. What you're doing in your for loop is accessing items at the index range `1 - 10`, which is skipping the item at `index 0` and attempting to access the item at `index 10`, which doesn't exist.

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < allterms.Count; i++ )
{
    excelApp.Cells[i + 1, 1] = allterms[i];
}
```

Comment: Very welcome, glad to help. If this (or any other response) answered your question, don't forget to mark it as such so others can know.

Answer (score 1):

In excel all indexes are 1-based. In C# all indexes are 0-based. In your code looks like you use 1-based access model for both: for excel and list.

Also, to increase the speed of inserting, it will be better to set values for range instead of for each cell. You can take a look on example I have here: http://outcoldman.com/en/blog/show/201

Comment: Could you post an example using my procedure  here please !!